# Check app running on new port

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, node-http-proxy, node-request

I need to create application which get request for specific port and proxy it to new server on different port

for example the following port 3000 will be proxy to port 9000
and you actually run the application on 9000 ( under the hood) since the user in the client click on 3000

http://localhost:3000/a/b/c

http://localhost:9000/a/b/c

I try something like

```
var proxy = httpProxy.createProxyServer({});

            http.createServer(function (req, res) {

                var hostname = req.headers.host.split(":")[0];
                var pathname = url.parse(req.url).pathname;
                proxy.web(req, res, {
                        target: 'http://' + hostname + ':' + 9000
                    });
     var proxyServer = http.createServer(function (req, res) {

                    res.end("Request received on " + 9000);
                });
                proxyServer.listen(9000);

            }).listen(3000, function () {

     });
```

1. Is the right way to do it?
2. How can I **test it**? I ask since if I run the node application in port 3000 I cannot put the first URL in the client http://localhost:3000/a/b/c since this port is already taken. Is there a workaround?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are few [examples](https://github.com/nodejitsu/node-http-proxy/tree/master/examples/http) on various usage of proxy server. Here is a simple example of a basic proxy server:

```
var http = require("http");
var httpProxy = require('http-proxy');

/** PROXY SERVER **/
var proxy = httpProxy.createServer({
  target:'http://localhost:'+3000,
  changeOrigin: true
})

// add custom header by the proxy server
proxy.on('proxyReq', function(proxyReq, req, res, options) {
  proxyReq.setHeader('X-Special-Proxy-Header', 'foobar');
});

proxy.listen(8080);

/** TARGET HTTP SERVER **/
http.createServer(function (req, res) {
  res.writeHead(200, { 'Content-Type': 'text/plain' });

  //check if the request came from proxy server
  if(req.headers['x-special-proxy-header'])
    console.log('Request received from proxy server.')

  res.write('request successfully proxied to: ' + req.url + '\n' + JSON.stringify(req.headers, true, 2));
  res.end();
}).listen(3000);
```

#### To Test if the proxy server working or if the request is coming from proxy server:

I've added a `proxyReq` listener which adds a custom header. You can tell from this header if the request came from the proxy server.

So, if you visit `http://localhost:8080/a/b/c` you'll see the `req.headers` has a header like this:

```
'X-Special-Proxy-Header': 'foobar'
```

This header is set only when client makes a request to 8080 port

But for `http://localhost:3000/a/b/c`, you won't see such header because client is bypassing the proxy server and that header is never set.

Comment: Thanks voted up !but how should I test it can you please explain ?

Comment: Thanks Hassasin!Voted up! one last question is now that I've the new server I need manually to switch to the new proxy port ,how should I under the hood navigate the call to the new port ?

Comment: In the above example, simply replace 8080 with 3000 and 3000 with 9000

Comment: Thanks but when I click on localhost:3000 I got in the json "host": "localhost:3000",I dont need to get 9000?

Comment: I see. you can set  `proxyReq.setHeader('host','localhost:9000')` - but there might be better way for it. I'll look into it.